# How can I undo traditional IRA contribution and contribute to Roth IRA instead?

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira, roth-conversion

I made a contribution to my traditional IRA account for 2021. Later I learned from my CPA that since we had already reached the deduction limit of 125k for a couple, we won't be getting any tax break for contribution to traditional IRA. So, I have been thinking if I won't be getting any tax break by contributing to the tax advantaged account, I might as well make a contribution to the Roth IRA instead.

Is there a way to do something like such?